# Does ArcGIS Desktop have conditional function useable in field calculations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

Does ArcGIS / ArcView 10 have a conditional function, e.g. ifx(test,if_T,if_F), that could be in-lined in field calculations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using a code block in the Field Calculator.

There are several examples of doing this in its **[Online Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000)**.

For example:

```
Parser:
Python

Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
  if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
    return 1
  elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
    return 2
  elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
    return 3
  elif (WellYield > 30):
    return 4
```